# Modifying value using before_validation before validate_uniqueness_of - SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, url

I'm trying to ensure the uniqueness of some urls we store in my app. 
I want to strip them of their query parameters as these can change for the same url, and certain urls needs a slightly different stripping algorithm.

I have a method (in an initializer)

```
def clean_url(url)
  domain = get_domain(url)
  case domain
  when "xyz.com" || "xyz.co.uk"
    url = url.split("&")[0]
  when "abc.com"
    url = url.split("?")[0]
  end
end
```

I want to call url_cleaner before_validation

```
thing.rb

before_validation :url_cleaner
validates_uniqueness_of :url

def url_cleaner
  self.url = clean_url(self.url)     
end
```

And I'm getting

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Comment: Could you please provide top of backtrace (about 50 line)?

Comment: How do I do that? I'm literally getting a one line error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that your before_validation method is trying to save the object, which in turn kicks off the before_validation and it goes into a loop - that's what's causing `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

What's causing some confusion here is that your choice of local variable (`url`) within that method is the same as the actual attribute "url", which is accessed via the method "def url".  You see what i mean?  lots of different things called "url" here.  I'd make it so that you always just refer to the one thing, which is `self.url`.  I'd rewrite the above like so:

```
before_validation :clean_url
validates_uniqueness_of :url

def clean_url
  case get_domain(self.url)
  when "xyz.com" || "xyz.co.uk"
    self.url = self.url.split("&")[0]
  when "abc.com"
    self.url = self.url.split("?")[0]
  end
end
```

Does it still go into a loop if you do this?  If so, can you add the definition of the `get_domain` method to your question?  Maybe something in here is trying to save or validate the object.

Comment: That was basically the issue, in the end I went with - 
before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.ad_url = clean_url(self.url) if attribute_present?("url")
  end

And that did the trick, but I think the reasoning was the same above.

Answer (score 0):

As per Max's logic above, I ended up doing the following:

```
before_validation(on: :create) do 
  self.ad_url = clean_url(self.url) if attribute_present?("url") 
end
```

And that did the trick